# PhpStorm live template variable default value - directory of file

Tags: phpstorm, live-templates

I've created live template that uses variables, something like :

```
A::set($CATEGORY$,$MESSAGE$);
```

And I want to set default value of variable `$CATEGORY$` as a directory, where the file I've used this live template located.
There is expression `fileName()` that does a thing close to my task.

So if I use my live template in file located `app\views\home\index.php` - I would like to get default value for `$CATEGORY$` - `'home'`. How can I do this?

Comment: From one of the 2017.x version PhpStorm supports [GroovyScript in Live Templates](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-19413) -- you can code such extraction of `home` from the value returned by `fileName()` function yourself (there is no built-in Live Template function to do that). You may check https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155907#comment=27-2662765 for some info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it using GroovyScript as LazyOne says. Didn't found what value live template function groovyScript() will output, but my code doing what i wanted.

Solution:

```
String path = _editor.getVirtualFile().getPath();
Integer lastIndex = path.lastIndexOf('/');
Integer startIndex = path.substring(0,lastIndex).lastIndexOf('/')+1;
path.substring(startIndex,lastIndex);
```

Comment: I have followed the references from LazyOne's answer, but if I wanted to make a script which I call by file name, how do I pass the `filePath()` as a parameter and receive it in the script?
I assume I would call the script with `groovyScript("~/my_file", filePath())`